# Switchee, Stash, Low Variables, Playa and Parse Order

Tags: playa, stash, low-variables, parse-order, switchee

I’m curious about a parse order issue I’m running into with Low Variables and Stash.

I have a client site that’s using Switchee, Stash, Low Variables and Playa. I am able to retrieve the custom fields just fine inside of the tag, but for whatever reason, I am unable to retrieve the url_title. It just simply doesn’t render any value.

**Here’s the page template:**

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}
    {case value=""}
        {embed="layouts/.default"}

        {exp:stash:set name='pagetitle'}Gay Blog — The New GayTravel.com!{/exp:stash:set}
        {exp:stash:set name='bodyclass'}blog index{/exp:stash:set}

        {exp:stash:set name='maincontent' parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="3" parse_conditionals="yes"}

            <div class="main-banner">
                <figure>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h1 class="header"><a href="#">Featured Story: <br />Gay Travel Guru’s Visit to Phuket</a></h1>
                        <p>Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
                        <a class="read-more" href="#">Read More »</a>
                    </figcaption>
                    <img src="http://flickholdr.iwerk.org/1280/800/gay, thailand, male" alt="Placeholder image from flickholdr.com" />
                </figure>
                {lv_ad_top_banner_square}
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <main role="main">
                    <section class="content-block">
                        <h1>Gay Blog Featured Articles</h1>
                        <div class="slider-box clearfix">
                            {exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_blog_featured_articles" limit="3" var_prefix="blog"}
                                <article class="blog-block element-block">
                                    <figure>
                                        <figcaption><a href="{blog:url_title_path='blog'}">{entry_date format="%M %d, %Y"}</a></figcaption>
                                        {exp:ce_img:single src="{blog:blog_main_image}" width="500" allow_scale_larger="yes" height="300" attributes='alt="{blog:title}"' crop="yes"    }
                                    </figure>
                                    <h2><a href="{blog:url_title_path='blog'}">{title}</a></h2>
                                    {blog:blog_summary}
                                </article>
                            {/exp:low_variables:parse}
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section class="content-block">
                        <h1>Latest Video Blog</h1>
                        <article class="video-blog-block element-block">
                            <div class="video-container">
                                <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dFVxGRekRSg" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
                            </div>
                            <h2><a href="#">Video Blog Page Title</a></h2>
                            <p>Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida     at eget metus.</p>
                        </article>
                    </section>
                    <section class="content-block">
                        <h1>Blog Archives</h1>
                        <div class="archive-wrapper">
                            {exp:channel:entries
                                channel="blogs"
                                disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks"
                                dynamic="off"
                                limit="12"
                            }
                                <article class="blog-archive element-block">
                                    <figure>
                                        <figcaption><a href="{url_title_path='blog'}">{entry_date format="%M %d"}</a></figcaption>
                                        {exp:ce_img:single src="{blog_main_image}" width="500" allow_scale_larger="yes" height="300" attributes='alt="{title}"' crop="yes"}
                                    </figure>
                                    <h2><a href="{url_title_path='blog'}">{title}</a></h2>
                                </article>
                                {switch="||<div class='clear-left'></div>"}
                            {/exp:channel:entries}
                        </div>
                        <a class="button" href="#">View the Rest of the Archive »</a>
                    </section>
                </main>
                <div class="sidebar">
                    {lv_sidebar_featured_members}
                    {lv_sidebar_get_the_updates}
                    {lv_ad_sidebar_tower}
                    {lv_sidebar_tweets}
                </div>
            </div>
        {/exp:stash:set}
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

My Low Variable Extension settings are set to parse before snippets, and my Low Variable entry has early parsing turned on.

Also, you can see that I’ve already got parse_depth set to a level of 3, and it’s still not rendering anything. I got the solution/suggestion [from this article](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11742/playa-in-a-low-variable-and-stash)

As I mentioned before, everything seems to work, except for the url_title, which just has a blank value.

Any thoughts on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this was actually an error on the part of the original data migration. I really should have checked that out first. It seems that the url_titles were never migrated, for whatever reason that could be.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6x457jdgwzsu37/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-29%20at%203.16.36%20AM.png